# How to bind to the new Set and Map objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Does angular 1.* ng-repeat work with `Set` and `Map` new objects?

Are there any plans to integrate this?

Comment: Have you tried and failed miserably?

Comment: I guess you talk about Angular 1.3?

Answer (score 1):

Angular internally uses `for..in` operator to iterate through non-array objects. [Proof-link to the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2a156c2d7ec825ff184480de9aac4b0d7fbd5275/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L419). `Map` and `Set` can't be iterated by this way, they should be iterated via `for..of`. So you can't use this collections for `ng-repeat` without any extra conversions.

Upcoming Angular 2 have ES6 features support and it have for..of syntax in repeat too. See [angular 2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/919) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to bind a `Map` to `ng-repeat` in Angular 2. Even with `*ngFor="let item of items"` it did not work. Instead, this solved the problem for me:

```
/*
 * Extension of the ES6 map, which also supports binding to it's array of values
 */
class BindableMap extends Map {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.bindableValues = [];
    }

    updateBindableValues() {
        // Clear the array without creating a new one.
        this.bindableValues.length = 0;
        // Push all the new values
        this.bindableValues.push(...Array.from(super.values()));
    }

    clear(...args) {
        super.clear(...args);
        this.updateBindableValues();
    }

    set(...args) {
        super.set(...args);
        this.updateBindableValues();
    }

    delete(...args) {
        super.delete(...args);
        this.updateBindableValues();
    }
}
```

This way you can use it also in Angular 1.x with `ng-repeat="value in map.bindableValues"`.

Note that this is not the most efficient solution, as the bindable values get recreated on every change of the map. For my  purposes it sufficed though. Also, you can extend the `BindableMap` to bind to keys or key-value pairs as well, if you wish.