# How to use ES6 Map with AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

Is the **ng-repeat** of AngularJS 1.x compatible with **ES6 Maps**?

Comment: see this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201034/keeping-insertion-order-angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngRepeat` currently doesn't support `Map`.. to use it either you have to convert it into a JavaScript Array first.. or write a filter to convert it while using it.

see [angular-toArrayFilter](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter) for reference. You can also create you very own filter like ***toArraFilter*** and use it with `Map` inside `ngRepeat`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to create your own angular filter as [@Minato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35337638/6667806) suggested.

You can use ES6 Spread syntax to convert map into array:

```
angular.module('SomeModuleName')
.filter('mapToArray', function() {
    return function(map) {
        return [...map.values()];
    };
});
```

And then just use it in the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Map | mapToArray">
```

You can also use lodash toArray method:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toArray

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972685/2628369) for a solution to bind `ng-repeat` to an ES6 `Map` in Angular 1.x.